# How to redirect to Home page after rendering the Header component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have created a "header" that gets all the menu and its content from the backend application.

**Header.js**

```
 {getMenus.map(getMenu => (
            <Button
              key={getMenu.name}
              variant="text"
              color="inherit"
            >
              <Link
                style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "white" }}
                // to={getMenu.link}
                to={getMenu.link.concat(
                  getMenu.link === "/" ? "" : "/",
                  getMenu.id
                )}
              >
                {getMenu.name}
              </Link>
            </Button>
          ))}
```

getMenus is list of menu, which will be displayed in the header. I have used **react router** to display relevent content of menu.

**App.js**

```
<Router>
      <div className="App">
        <Header />

        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/hello/:id" exact component={Hello} />
        <Switch>

       <Footer>
     </div>
</Router>
```

When I start my react application, I see blank space in the middle section because I have not clicked on any menu.
How can I render Home component, whenever I start the react application?

Comment: `<Redirect to="/hello/id" />`

Answer (score 0):

In Header.js, once the API call is complete, call `this.props.history.push('/home/{id}')` to load the page with the id from the call.

**An example within a class based component:**

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        apiCall().then(id => {
            this.props.history.push('/hello/' + id);
        })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            null
        );
    }
}
```

Further reading on `props.history`.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history

Comment: can you please elaborate history.push() or  point me to blog or video. I am new to react.

Answer (score 0):

Would help in providing a dynamic ID as well

```
    < Redirect to={`/hello/${id}`} />
```

Comment: I want the Home component to be rendered when the application first starts and the path will be "/4" something like this